# Hot air balloon Related Rates

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

> A man in a hot air balloon is ascending at a rate of $10\frac{ft}{sec}$. How fast is the distance from the balloon to the horizon ( the distance the man can see ) increasing when the balloon is $1,000$ feet high. (Hint: assume the earth is a ball of radius $4000$ miles).

**My Attempt:** Please tell me where it is wrong.

First we construct a triangle such that,

$x=$ radius of the earth in feet $=4000*5280$

$y=$ height of ballon in feet $=1000$

$z=$ distance the man can see in feet $=\sqrt{1000^2+(4000\times5280)^2}$

So, $$\frac{dx}{dt}=0, \frac{dy}{dt}=10\frac{ft}{sec}$$
We need to solve for $\frac{dz}{dt}$.
$$x^2+y^2=z^2 \implies 2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}=2z\frac{dz}{dt} \implies \frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{x\frac{dx}{dt}+y\frac{dy}{dt}}{z}$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{(4000\times5280)(0)+(1000)(10)}{\sqrt{1000^2+(4000\times5280)^2}} $$
Right here is where everything feels wrong. Is $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$? Can anyone please help me close this guy off, and did I let $x$ equal the correct value?

Comment: The distance the man can see in feet can be calculated by observing that the man's sight line to the horizon is tangent to earth at the horizon. Then imagine a line at the horizon to the center of the earth. Those two lines are perpendicular. The hypotenuse is the distance from the center of the earth to the man in the balloon. So distance to horizon is $\sqrt{(1000+5280*4000)^2-(5280*4000)^2}$.  Regarding the rest, yes $x$ is a constant, so its derivative is zero. Other than that looks OK.

Comment: @Χpẘ I thought that the distance the man sees has to be the hypotenuse because we know $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$?

Comment: I suggest drawing it out.  The way you have it, the man will see over 4000 miles to the horizon. But from a commercial plane the distance is close to 200 miles, so at 1000 ft the distance must be smaller  than 200 miles. Around 40 miles. I can write up a full answer if you want.

Comment: @Χpẘ that would be awesome if you could and maybe with an image because im having trouble with mine. As it stands ihave a sphere with the balloon above and the horizon off to th side

Answer (score 0):

Let $d$ be distance to horizon, $r$ be radius of earth, $h$ be the balloon's height, $s$ is balloon's speed, and $t$ is time. The OP gives $r,h,s,t$ in different units, but the units conversion in the following is implicit.

The man's line of sight is tangent to the earth at the horizon. At the horizon the line segment to the center of the earth is perpendicular to the surface of the earth and to the man's line of sight. Thus the line of sight and the line segment to the center of the earth at the horizon at the two short legs of a right triangle. The hypotenuse is the line segment from the man to the center of the earth. So $(h+r)^2=d^2+r^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{2rh+h^2}=d$.

$h=t*v+h_0$ giving $$d=\sqrt{2r(t*v+h_0)+(t*v+h_0)^2} \Rightarrow
d=\sqrt{v^2t^2+2v(r+h_0)t+(2r+h_0)h_0}$$

Both sides must be differentiated WRT to $t$, giving:
$$d^\prime =\frac{v^2t+v(r+h_0)}{\sqrt{v^2t^2+2v(r+h_0)t+(2r+h_0)h_0}}$$

I calculated the horizon at 1000 and 1010 feet and it matches pretty well with the formula above with $t=0$, but recommend you double check everything.